expectation functional property
I'm trying to solve the second statement of the following exercise. It is Exercise 2.5 of "All of Nonparametric Statistics, Larry Wasserman".

My try:
\begin{align}
|T(F)-T(G)| &= \left|\int x dF - \int x dG\right| \\
            &= \left|\int x d(F-G)\right| \\
            &\leq \int |x|d(|F-G|) \\
            &\leq M \int d(|F-G|) \\
            &\leq M \sup_{x}|F(x)-G(x)|
\end{align}
I can not verify the last inequality. Is it true?

Reminds me of the upper bound limit of a Riemann-Stieltjes integral on a closed interval.

How did you write the last expression? The integration is on a bounded set?

@User1865345 I wrote the last inequality without proof. It may or may not be true. Anyway,  I want to solve the second statement.

@User1865345 You can assume the integral is defined on a bounded set, because $|X| \leq M$ for some $M$.
